# angular js date validation message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do from date, to date validation (todate > fromdate).

please check my html code

```
    From Date <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="fromDate" min-view="1"
ng-change="getFromMonth(newcashbenifit.toDate, newcashbenifit.fromDate);"
name="cbFromdate" ng-model="newcashbenifit.fromDate" autoclose="true" bs-datepicker />


To Date<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="toDate" min-view="1"
 ng-change="getToMonth(newcashbenifit.toDate, newcashbenifit.fromDate);"
 class="form-control" name="cbTodate" autocomplete="off"
ng-model="newcashbenifit.toDate" bs-datepicker />
```

i am using below functions to validate this. please check below functions

```
        $scope.getToMonth = function (selectedToMonth,selectedFromMonth){

            if(selectedFromMonth > selectedToMonth ){
                    $scope.cashBenefitForm.cbTodate.$setValidity("message", false)
            }else{
                $scope.cashBenefitForm.cbTodate.$setValidity("message", true)
            }
         }

         $scope.getFromMonth = function (selectedToMonth,selectedFromMonth){
            if(selectedFromMonth > selectedToMonth ){
                    $scope.cashBenefitForm.cbFromdate.$setValidity("message2", false)
            }else{
                $scope.cashBenefitForm.cbFromdate.$setValidity("message2", true)
            }
          }
```

Validation is working well. please check below image. 
[image]

validation working correctly. Now i changed From date as '04/2020'. in the occasion, to date validation still appear. it should remove, because now todate > fromdate.  check attached image
[image]

how i do this validation correctly. ?

Comment: so when you change the from date only getFromMonth function is called you can add the check in this function.

Comment: Hi Prashantha,  sorry i did not get u

Comment: The method validating the to date is only called when the to date is changed. To work correctly you must also validate the to date when the from date is changed.